# class Schema not found in App Service Provider - even when i added use Schema;

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I faced an error when i uploaded my application online although that error didn't appear on my localhost

[image]

Here is how my appserviceprovider.php look like

And before you say it i changed

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
```

To

```
use Schema;
```

And i still have the same problem

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use DB;
use View;
use Request;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //Check for database connection
        try {
            DB::connection()->getPdo();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            if (Request::is('database/setup')) {
                echo View::make('common/database/setup', array('error' => $e->getMessage()));

                die();
            }
            else {
                echo View::make('errors/database', array('error' => $e->getMessage()));

                die();
            }
        }

        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

       /*if (Schema::hasTable('categories')) {
           $categories = DB::table('categories')->get();

            view()->composer('frontend.layouts.include.header', function($view) use ($categories){
                $view->with('categories',$categories);
            });
       }

        if (Schema::hasTable('tags')) {
           $tags = DB::table('tags')->get();

            view()->composer('frontend.layouts.include.sidebar', function($view) use ($tags){
                $view->with('tags',$tags);
            });
        }*/
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Weird, I tried using `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;` and adding in the `boot` method :  `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);` and everything seems fine. P.S:I'm also on 5.4. Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: This may sound a bit dumb, but did you do `composer install`? That's the kind of thing we sometimes forget to do…

Comment: You have to use  `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;` and I saw you include this, so I guess the issue is you are working in boot method which runs once when application starts, so you need to restart the server. also, clear the cache and config.
Hope its works.

Comment: Find terminal in cpanel and run command `composer dump -a` after that `php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. So  I just include

**use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;**

at the top  of AppServiceProvider class  I and the problem solved.

using Laravel 5.8